# Use selenium to click button and view more text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Crawling data from "https://us.burberry.com/womens-new-arrivals-new-in/". I need to scroll down the page and click on "View 126 more" to get more text. This is the location to click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Class("shelf-view-more-button-copy"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

as i checked the url, there is just one class with value: `shelf-view-more-button-copy`

so i think you can use this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='shelf-view-more-button-copy']")).click();
```

if you want to also scroll to it you can add this code before that:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='shelf-view-more-button-copy']"));

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element);
```

Comment: findElement - is coming from from selenium import webdriver

Comment: webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class'shelf-view-more-button-copy']")).click();
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-8240997fbeae>", line 1, in <module>
    webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class'shelf-view-more-button-copy']")).click();

AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'findElement'

Comment: Use "find_element_by_xpath".

Comment: I am using xpath - not working                 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="facet-result-render"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/div/div[1]').click();